# WP7 - ContextMenu doesn't show on Hyperlink

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, contextmenu

I'm trying to programmatically add a ContextMenu to a Hyperlink. I've searched in the documentation and in forums, and seems that the correct solution should be this:

```
var link = new Hyperlink();
link.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = linkText });
link.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
link.TargetName = linkText;
link.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(link_Click);

ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(CopyLink);
item.Header = "copy link";
item.Tag = linkText;
menu.Items.Add(item);
ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu(link, menu);
```

This code compiles and does not throw any exception. I've tested and the ContextMenu is indeed added to the Hyperlink. The problem is that it will not show anytime. I can tap & hold the link all the time of the world and the menu will not appear. Also tried to add a listener with GestureService and GestureListener, but the Hold event does not fire at all.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer while reading the Windows Phone 7.5 Unleashed book by Daniel Vaughan. My problem was that I needed to add a hyperlink in a RichTextBox, and I can only use Inlines to show text. Hyperlink is an Inline, but does not support ContextMenu. As Tim suggested, I needed to use HyperlinkButton. The solution is that there is a class called [InlineUIContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.documents.inlineuicontainer.aspx).  So, this

```
var inline = new InlineUIContainer { Child = SomeHyperlinkButton }
```

made the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `ContextMenu`s on [`Hyperlink`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). You can do it on a [`HyperlinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), though. I'm not exactly sure of the reason, but it does work. Depending on what you're trying to do, `HyperlinkButton` may have been what you wanted anyway [(`Hyperlink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is usually only used inside documents of text).

Comment: I can only use Hyperlink, because the links are inside a block of text. So sad I can only use it with Buttons...